# How to work with JSON coming from api-platform

Tags: json, twig, symfony-3.4, api-platform.com

I've installed the [api-platform](https://api-platform.com/) demo on a server and I did a client app (working with Symfony 3.3) and I want to display the response in a classic view (Twig).

Everything's working fine : I can request and retrieve the response.

But here's where i'm stuck : when I dump the response in my view I got this

```
 {"@context":"\/contexts\/Book","@id":"\/books","@type":"hydra:Collection","hydra:member":[{"@id":"\/books\/1","@type":"Book","id":1,"isbn":"9783161484100","title":"1st Book","description":"This is my first book synopsis","author":"Hemingroad","publicationDate":"2018-02-16T14:15:58+00:00","reviews":[]}],"hydra:totalItems":1}
```

Here's my controller's method :

```
 //...
 use GuzzleHttp\Client;

public function newAction(Request $request)
{
     //initialize client API
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'http://my.apidomain.com/',
        'timeout'  => 2.0,
    ]);

    //request to API
    $dataBooks = $client->request('GET', 'books', ['auth' => ['login', 'p@$$w0rd']]);
    $listBooks = $dataBooks->getBody()->getContents();
    return $this->render('book/new.html.twig', array(
        'listBooks'   => $listBooks
    ));
}
```

I've also tried to json_decode and using [JMSSerializer](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) on $listBooks.
I got a beautiful object but I still cant access the JSON attribute's like ISBN, title by doing something like

```
 {% for book in listBooks %}
      {{ dump(book.title) }}
       <!-- .... -->
 {% endfor %}
```

Here's what I got when I json_decode $listBooks :

```
  {{ dump(listBooks) }}
```

[image]

I got an error when I try to access every field like this

```
  {{ dump(listBooks.@id) }}
  {{ dump(listBooks['hydra:member']) }}
  ....
```

Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: You should consider replacing the images with "real" text. Easier to read and to understand.

Comment: What does `{{ dump(book) }}` inside the `for` loop give you?

Comment: Have you tried for books in listBooks['hydra:member']? Seems the array of books is hydra:member.

Comment: @martias : it gives me nothing

Comment: @user9189147 : I got the following  error when I tried to access this field : "Impossible to access a key "hydra:member" on an object of class "stdClass" that does not implement ArrayAccess interface."

Comment: `$dataBooks->getBody()->getContents();` returns a string ([source](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#using-responses)), so you probably need to e.g. use `json_decode`. You said it doesn't work; why not? If you do `$listBooks = json_decode($listBooks);` and then `dump` it in Twig, what do you get?

Comment: @martias : when I use json_decode and dump it in twig, I got the last screenshot. But I still cant acess the book's attribute

Comment: Try `json_decode($listBooks, true);` so you'll get an associative array instead of an object. Then you might be able to do `{{ dump(listBooks['hydra:member']) }}` etc.

Comment: @martias : That's it ! Can you post your answser so I can mark it as the correct one, thank you again !

Comment: Yay! Will do when I'm on my computer, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$dataBooks->getBody()->getContents();` returns a string, as described in [Guzzle's documentation](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#using-responses), so you need to use [`json_decode`](https://secure.php.net/json_decode).

`$listBooks = json_decode($listBooks);` returns an object. In Twig you can use the dot notation to access methods and properties of an object, e.g. `{{ listBooks.myProp }}`. But because `hydra:member` includes a special character (`:`), you need to use [Twig's `attribute` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html), as described in [Twig's documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables):

```
{{ attribute(listBooks, 'hydra:member') }}
```

---

Another approach is to do `$listBooks = json_decode($listBooks, true);` so that you get an associative array instead of an object. Then you can use the bracket notation in Twig:

```
{{ listBooks['hydra:member'] }}
```

I would prefer this second approach, because in my opinion `{{ listBooks['hydra:member'] }}` is much clearer and cleaner than `{{ attribute(listBooks, 'hydra:member') }}`.